# Flask - implement "server busy"

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, server, semaphore

I have a Flask app, in every 5 seconds, client makes a call to `/process` route, sometimes it takes too much time to execute and sometimes not. I have used semaphores, so that, this route can be accessed only one at a time. If this route take long time to execute, and in this time, the client make a call, I don't want the client to keep waiting, so I will `abort`.

Just to mock some random time of execution, I am using `sleep` method, this will make the program sleep for randomly chosen number of seconds from a list. I am using `Semaphore` with `1` as limit, so that, this route can be accessed only one at a time. And, I am acquiring the resource, with `blocking=False` option, so that client is not blocked until the resource is released. Below is, how my code look like:

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, abort
from threading import Semaphore
import time
from random import choice


app = Flask(__name__)
sem = Semaphore(1)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/process')
def process():
    if sem.acquire(blocking=False):
        random_sleep_list = [2, 5, 7]
        random_sleep_selected = choice(random_sleep_list)
        print('Random Sleep: ', random_sleep_selected)
        time.sleep(random_sleep_selected)
        sem.release()
        return 'Done'
    else:
        abort(503)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**index.html**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log('Start')
            $.get('/process', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }).fail(function() {
                alert('Server busy!');
            });
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

The above code doesn't work properly, if the `/process` route takes long time to execute, and the client makes a call, the client keeps waiting, when actually it should not, because, the semaphore has already acquired the resource, and it will release only when, the randomly chosen number of seconds are finished.

I want to know, is there any Flask's inbuilt methods or decorators to say, "server is busy" or something like that, when the route is busy. Or this can be done with few modifications in my code. Let me know, what I am doing wrong, and how this can be solved.

Thanks in advance!

**Note:** I have tried starting the Flask app with `threaded=True` option, but this also doesn't work.

---

Any updates please?

Comment: I made a short test (with `threaded=True`). I did not use the javascript, I did run `wget` from command line on two terminals and I think the semaphore works. I had to fix one error though: `abort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status'`.

Comment: @VPfB, thanks for trying. Because, it's be 2-3 days, and nobody replied on this. This even works in 2 different tabs. The thing is, I am not reloading the page, I am calling an endpoint and retrieving some data. And I think, correct me if I am wrong, `wget` command will act like reloading.

Comment: You can fix `abort() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status'` by passing a HTTP status code, like `503`.

Comment: The way Flask web apps work is always request -> response. I think it does not matter what tool (`wget`, `curl`, or a browser) is used to send the request and collect the response.

Comment: But calling an endpoint from a JS framework should work in the similar fashion right?

Comment: I think yes, but here is a big disclaimer: I do not work with JS.